# What is the proper way to return custom 422 entity errors from CakePHP 3.8 model on beforeSave()and halt save() call?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am currently working on adding 422 http validation errors to a Cake 3.8 based API.

For the Tasks controller I have something like:

```
<?php

class TasksController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
    }

    public function add(string $id): void
    {
        $validationErrors = [];

        $task = $this->newEntity($this->request->getData(););

        if ($this->Tasks->save($task)) {
            // Errors added to entity in before save will not cause
            // save() to return false and stop the proccess from
            // making it here
            $this->response = $this->response->withStatus(200);
        } else {
            $validationErrors = [$task->getErrors()];
            if (count($validationErrors) > 0) {
                $this->response = $this->response->withStatus(422);
            } else {
                throw new BadRequestException("The posted entity is is invalid.");
            }
        }

        // Render json output for success / errors
        $this->set($this->createViewVars(['entity' => $task], $validationErrors));
    }
}
```

And for the TasksTable I have something like:

```
<?php

class TasksTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
    }

    public function beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $task, ArrayObject $options)
    {
        parent::beforeSave($event, $task, $options);

        $task->setError('technician', 'No default technician was able to be found');

        if(count($task->getErrors()) > 0) {
            $event->stopPropagation();
        }

    }
}
```

There are certain processes compiling data on beforeSave and beforeMarshal that may detect issues with the add request not being compatible with the system configuration, and these need to throw validation errors.

Part 1:

The current code in the above Table is able to catch errors in the beforeSave method on the Table and stop the database transaction with $event->stopPropagation(). However I am wondering what the proper way is to return the unsaved task entity with with errors attached to it from the table? I could store the entity to the task modes and use a custom getter to do this, but it seems like there would be some built in functionality to handle this?

Part 2:

Is there a way that I can trigger to $this->Tasks->save($task) to fail (return false) in beforeSave as well as stopping the query with $event->stopPropagation()?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `beforeMarshal` seems like the wrong place to do that. Is there some reason that it can't go in the normal validation (which happens when patching the entity) or rules (which happens before saving)? Both of these are built for exactly this sort of thing. Also, you shouldn't need to stop propagation of the event; the save will not go through if there are any errors in the entity.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Looking through the code I could probably shift what is in beforeMarshal into beforeSave, if that is desirable? This logic is basically combing through site settings and auto-filling certain fields based on settings in the system, so it is not validation code, it just reveals validation issues in the process of pre-populating itself. It's possible for these values to come from the end user sometimes, in which case this logic will not even run. I suppose we could leave the fields blank and let them fall onto the validation system in the case that there is nothing to pre-populate?

Comment: I removed the beforeMarshal part of the question since, it can be worked around.

Comment: I think that the most "Cake way" to do what you're talking about might be to use `beforeSave` to fill in the field, and then let the rules check whether those values are valid.

Comment: @GregSchmidt `beforeSave` happens after applying application rules.

Comment: Right! I meant `beforeRules`. :-(

Comment: @GregSchmidt That's certainly an option, but the event isn't triggered in case `checkRules` is disabled. I'd say your first instinct that data manipulation should go into `beforeMarshal()` was right, at least as far as request data goes. Further manipulation of the valid entity and manual abortion of the saving process should IMHO go into `beforeSave()`. I'm not sure what the problem with the shown code is, even though it will not cause `false` to be returned but `null` (use `$event->setResult(false)` or `return false`), it should still abort the saving process and go into the `else` branch.